# I can see all images in frontend but the images and label are not in admin

Tags: product, import, image

I have Uploaded 20K products by `.csv`.
Uploaded all images to `/media/import/` and put `/imagename.jpg` in `.csv`

It works fine in store front.
But Images tab in admin is empty. There's no image and label for any product...

Kindly give me a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by listing the "Media Gallery's" Attribute ID in the field "_media_attribute_id".

Field _media_attribute_id is the attribute id of the “media_gallery” attribute.

You can find it by going to “Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes” and searching by “media_gallery” in the “Attribute Code”.

Click it and you will find the attribute id in the URL. In our example it is 88.

https://domainname.com/ADMIN/catalog_product_attribute/edit/attribute_id/88/key/gg73744bd0114d0oo935xe7yuo547fs3/

Comment: Hello. What do you mean by "fixed the issue by listing media gallery's attribute id in the field _media_attribute_id"? My attribute id is 88, as well.

Comment: @Milos: Is possible import images label by using CSV after imported all images.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is likely caused by not assigning any images to the thumbnail, small or default image in the import CSV. This way they do get linked to the product just fine but are not propperly linked to one of the seperate "defaults".

This blog post by MagePsycho has a great explanation on how to fix this issue without having to go through the entire import again.
http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/how-to-fix-the-issue-product-images-missing-in-backend-but-not-in-frontend/

Comment: Welcome. Single link answers are not seen as good answers. Please add more explanations to your answer.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to expand.

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment yet, so will post this as an answer. Following on from @Pratik Kamani's point (https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/70823/28911), this solved my problem as well.

I suspect that in my case it was due to the client specifying the same image to be used for both simple products and their parent configurable product. I still need to do more testing to confirm this though.

Comment: you can give me upvote to my answer if it solve your problem .

Answer (score 2):

**Try This below Solution**

> Open up the following file:

```
lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php
```

> Find this line :

chmod($destinationFile, 0640);

> Replace it with this line:

chmod($destinationFile, 0777);

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have added the images to the `thumbnail`, `small_image` or `image` field but haven't added the image to the `_media_image` field (if you are using the 'new' Mage_ImportExport module.

The problem you are now probably experiencing is when you save the products, you loose all the images.

The reference what is happening in the code: https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.8/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Product.php#L1237

Answer (score 1):

problem is configurable swatches with magento 1.9.1.0. i have same issue , i use magmi to import item, disable this and works fine.

Try disabling configurable swatches in 
System > Configuration > Catalog > Configurable Swatches
That seems to fix the issue for me.
I dont know why Configurable Swatches is removing entries from the tables catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value and catalog_product_entity_media_gallery. But ill try to find a fix..

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue and was able to solve it by adding the following to my */etc/hhvm/server.ini* file.

```
hhvm.enable_zend_ini_compat=false
```

This will only work if you are using HHVM which was what was causing my problem.  More details of this issue can be found [here at GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/4993).