# Images Import Successfully But Images Not shown - Import By Magmi?

Tags: magento-1.9, backend, media-images, gallery-image

How can I solve the error, images import successfully and images saved into **catalog/product/desired folder**, but images not shown front end backend. Images imported by using MAGMI.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Possible reason 1:** You have wrong permissions on your /media/ folder.

Ensure you have writable permissions on this folder. Change permissions to 777 recursively. You can do it using SSH via this command (execute it in Magento directory):

Change ownership of the /media/ folder:

```
chmod -R 777 media/
```

**Possible reason 2:** Magento cannot resize images due low PHP memory limit. Magento resize images using GD library, however if there is no sufficient amount of memory for such operation Magento will return a placeholder image.

Increase your memory limit. You should open your .htaccess file and find this string:

```
 php_value memory_limit 512M
```

**Possible reason 3 :** Uploader file

To fix this issue you had to revert change the permissions to more realistic values, 775 for folders and 644 for files. These can be changed here;

```
lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php
```

line 219, change 0640 to 0644 line 541, change 0750 to 0755

Comment: media permissions = 777, php_value memory_limit 99999M, Uploader.php = 777, still not working. Actually i am try to access imags from other server using magmi

Comment: After your correction, still not working...

Comment: @zus Are you importing all the images from magmi using csv?

Comment: yes,  i am importing all images from magmi by remote like another server. my CSV: https://snag.gy/2oPART.jpg

Comment: @zus Check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11309/i-can-see-all-images-in-frontend-but-the-images-and-label-are-not-in-admin

Comment: There is no relevant information for me, my issue products images successfully getting from another server like remote and store into desired products images folder, and the products images link also correct but i don't know why https://i.stack.imgur.com/WO33S.png....

Comment: i can't view my images from image location, all images file size 0.

Comment: console error : https://snag.gy/haNQkx.jpg

Comment: Try this http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/how-to-fix-the-issue-product-images-missing-in-backend-but-not-in-frontend/

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to comment but I would suggest opening the image location directly in your browser or viewing the console to see if it gives you an exact error code to help rectify your issue.

For example if you're seeing an error message like the below it's likely permissions as Raghav mentions.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: In console, there is no error, like empty page : https://snag.gy/CXje2T.jpg

Comment: @zus How acount if you go directly to the image location in your browser? Also, does it work OK without using Magmi?

Comment: Make sure i am imported images accessing from another server like remote using magmi.

Comment: console error: https://snag.gy/haNQkx.jpg

Comment: @zus The console mentions URL's which may contain credentials are depreciated, is this potentially the issue? I.e. are your images stored on a different server to your website (from what I understand) and is that webserver protected with authentication which your website may not be able to display? Perhaps a different browser may allow that depreciation if that is the case?

Comment: Yes, I am accessing images from another server, and vice versa. The error is, magmi takes images from another server and put into my catalog/product/desired folder, in this process no error, but the images size is 0, i mean the complete migration is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurred usually the file encoding. Switching from ANSI to UTF-8 resolved it. Magento says import successful, and the query logs showed movements.

You must have next fields in CSV

```
sku   _attribute_set  _type   _category   description image   name    price   short_description   status  tax_class_id    thumbnail   visibility  weight  qty _product_websites   is_in_stock
```

Please note that field `is_in_stock` is mandatory even if qty more than 1.

Comment: I tried UTF-8 also,  still not working, and make sure i am imported product images using MAGMI and accessing another server.

Comment: @ zus Magmi, Magmi supports both local image & remote image import from URLs. it also supports image gallery to associate multiple images with a product All image import is done by using Image attributes processor:- http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php/Image_attributes_processor

Answer (score 0):

Take look on following step:

**Step 1**- Give media folder permission `chmod -R 777 media/*`

**Step 2**- Check **.htaccess** file present in media folder or not . If not upload **.htaccess** file in media folder copy from any local magento directory.

Hope this would help you out , **Step 2** is strongly recommended.

Comment: Media folder already have .htacess file.

Comment: all images file size 0, may i know why...

Comment: console error: https://snag.gy/haNQkx.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Change ownership of the /media/ folder:
chmod -R 777 media/